# юнити перезагружается после изменения скрипта

Tags: unity3d

после изменения скрипта в(ide) и возвращения в unity-editor я получаю это.
Oно компилируется каждый раз и занимает до двух секунд, можно ли избавиться от этого,
вроде бы писал на 2019 версии и такого не былo.
я читал про unity assembly definition

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я помню, так было всегда ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

А вообще, [вот](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/210452343-How-to-stop-automatic-assembly-compilation-from-script), вроде как, оно. Первая ссылка в гугле, если что)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: было бы круто чтобы оно само скомпилировалось после изменения скрипта а то приходится заходить в юнити и ждать. сделать ctrl+r не удобно если отключать ту опцию

Comment: про edit -> preferences asset pipeline -> auto refresh слышал, но изменение скриптов не отображается (alt+r) для обновления и пересборки.

Comment: @Lex, так ведь отключение автоматической перекомпиляци при изменении скриптов, это как раз то, что вы хотели, нет? Тогда "было бы круто чтобы оно само скомпилировалось после изменения скрипта" противоречит вопросу.

Comment: я имел в виду компиляцию проекта юнити пока я нахожусь в ide)

Comment: @Lex, [вроде как оно уже должно так работать с Visual Studio 2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-tools-for-unity-2019-causing-unity-to-recompile/602814)
"We added a feature to refresh the assets when you save so when you switch back to Unity there is less waiting time while it compiles."

Comment: попробую спасибо, я с vs code